# Performing bulk load in cassandra with map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, bulk-load, datastax-enterprise

I haven't got much experience working with cassandra, so please excuse me if I have put in a wrong approach.

I am trying to do bulk load in cassandra with map reduce

Basically the word count example

Reference : http://henning.kropponline.de/2012/11/15/using-cassandra-hadoopbulkoutputformat/

I have put the simple Hadoop Wordcount Mapper Example and slightly modified the driver code and the reducer as per the above example.

**I have successfully generated the output file as well. Now my doubt is how to perform the loading to cassandra part? Is there any difference in my approach ?**

Please advice.

This is a part of the driver code

```java
 Job job = new Job();
 job.setJobName(getClass().getName());
 job.setJarByClass(CassaWordCountJob.class);

 Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
 conf.set("cassandra.output.keyspace", "test");
 conf.set("cassandra.output.columnfamily", "words");
 conf.set("cassandra.output.partitioner.class", "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");
 conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.port","9160");    // default
 conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.address", "localhost");
 conf.set("mapreduce.output.bulkoutputformat.streamthrottlembits", "400");

 job.setMapperClass(CassaWordCountMapper.class);
 job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
 job.setReducerClass(CassaWordCountReducer.class);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/user/Desktop/test/cassandra")); 
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "reducer", BulkOutputFormat.class, ByteBuffer.class, List.class);
 return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Mapper is the same as the normal wordcount mapper that just tokenizes and emits Word, 1

The reducer class is of the form

```java
public class CassaWordCountReducer extends 
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, ByteBuffer, List<Mutation>> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<Mutation> columnsToAdd = new ArrayList<Mutation>();
        Integer wordCount = 0;
        for(IntWritable value : values) {
            wordCount += value.get();
        }
        Column countCol = new Column(ByteBuffer.wrap("count".getBytes()));
        countCol.setValue(ByteBuffer.wrap(wordCount.toString().getBytes()));
        countCol.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
        ColumnOrSuperColumn wordCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        wordCosc.setColumn(countCol);
        Mutation countMut = new Mutation();
        countMut.column_or_supercolumn = wordCosc;
        columnsToAdd.add(countMut);
        context.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.toString().getBytes()), columnsToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does not work in the code above, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Charles,I am not sure about the write operation to cassandra. Since I have specified the output location, I am getting a file output. My question is - do we need to perform some other operation to load this file to cassandra? Like for HBase, we do -

LoadIncrementalHFiles loadHfile = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(configuration);

loadHfile.doBulkLoad(new Path(resourcePath), hTable);

Comment: No you wouldn't have to load a file to cassandra. That's what the OutputFormat is for. Are you sure you're using the multiple outputformat in the right way?

Comment: I have made the change in the reducer according to the previous discussion  - 

multipleOutputs.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.toString().getBytes()),
    columnsToAdd, "reducer");

this is how the new code would look like. 

Even now the data is not getting inserted into Cassandra, nor is it showing any error or exception.

Comment: Though I have not performed any context writes I am getting two output files in my output path 

reducer-r-00000
words-r-00000

The second file being a blank text file and the first one a text file with contents as below

java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1 cap=1] [Mutation(column_or_supercolumn:ColumnOrSuperColumn(column:Column(name:63 6F 75 6E 74, value:31, timestamp:1360125545574)))]
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]
 [Mutation(column_or_supercolumn:ColumnOrSuperColumn(column:Column(name:63 6F 75 6E 74, value:31, timestamp:1360125545586)))]

etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do bulk loads into Cassandra, I would advise looking at [this article from DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading). Basically you need to do 2 things for bulk loading:

- Your output data won't natively fit into Cassandra, you  need to transform it to SSTables.
- Once you have your SSTables, you need to be able to stream them into Cassandra. Of course you don't simply want to copy each SSTable to every node, you want to only copy the relevant part of the data to each node

In your case when using the `BulkOutputFormat`, it should do all that as it's using the `sstableloader` behind the scenes. I've never used it with `MultipleOutputs`, but it should work fine.

I think the error in your case is that you're not using `MultipleOutputs` correctly: you're still doing a `context.write`, when you should really be writing to your `MultipleOutputs` object. The way you're doing it right now, since you're writing to the regular `Context`, it will get picked up by the default output format of `TextOutputFormat` and not the one you defined in  your `MultipleOutputs`. More information on how to use the `MultipleOutputs` in your reducer [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).

Once you write to the correct output format of `BulkOutputFormat` like you defined, your SSTables should get created and streamed to Cassandra from each node in your cluster - you shouldn't need any extra step, the output format will take care of it for you.

Also I would advise looking at [this post](http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.com/2012/03/bulkloadto-cassandra-with-hadoop.html), where they also explain how to use `BulkOutputFormat`, but they're using a `ConfigHelper` which you might want to take a look at to more easily configure your Cassandra endpoint.